# Change/Deactivate the shell for an amount of users on SUSE Enterprise Server

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a SUSE Server to which ~300 users are connecting.

About 100 of them have to be deactivated. I think it would be nice to change their shell to /bin/false either with chsh or with usermod.

Do I have to type every command per line, or can I fill out a list of users which can be read from the script?

I should mention that all of the 100 users have the same ending in their username. Can I work with wildcards here? e.g.

> usermod -s /bin/fish *ftpuser
>
> chsh -s /sbin/nologin *ftpuser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way would be to simply lock the account:

```
getent passwd|cut -d: -f1|while read user; do 
    case "$user" in 
        *ftpuser) passwd -l $user;;
    esac
done
```

The account could be reopened by doing the same thing again, but with `passwd -u` instead.

Comment: This would be fine. but there are also users which authenticate via SSH-Key. But Thanks a lot for this hint.

Comment: This one worked better than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a shell script like this:

```
getent passwd|cut -d: -f1|while read user; do 
    case "$user" in 
        *ftpuser) echo usermod -s /bin/false "$user";;
    esac
done
```

`getent passwd` gets the user list (same as `cat /etc/passwd` if you don't use LDAP or similar).

`cut -d: -f1` gets the first collum, e.g. the user.

The while loop reads each line of input and checks with case if the user matches the pattern.

I put in an `echo` before the `usermod` command so you can see what would be executed. If you're sure the commands are ok run the script without the echo.